numerical analysis convergence, Newton iteration
Consider Newton s method for finding a root of $f(x)=x^{4}-9$. Prove that for any initial point $x_{0}\in (\sqrt[4]{6},100)$, the number sequence ${x_{n}}$ generated by Newton s iteration converges to the root $p=\sqrt{3}$.
I tried to apply the error formula for Newton iteration which is $e_{n+1}\approx\frac{1}{2}\frac{f''(r)}{f'(r)}e_{n}^{2}$ but I could not obtain a result from here.

The error formula will not help to answer the question. You should study the function $f$ and look at the variations (increasing, decreasing...) of the sequence $x_n$ to derive a proof.

Idea is, that $g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is continuously differentiable with $g'(x_0)=0$. From condition $\max|g'|\leqslant K < 1$ and then using error formula you obtain interval for convergence. Sorry if this is not very clear, but in few words it's idea.

Thank you why do I need g'<K<1?

$\max|g'|\leqslant K < 1$ guarantees the convergence of Newton's sequence. I'll add source to answer.

Thank you if you add this will be fine for me

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth, $f(a) f(b) <0$, $f'\ne 0$, $f''$ does not change sign, and
$$\frac{|f(a)|}{|f'(a)|}< b-a, \frac{|f(b)|}{|f'(b)|}< b-a $$
Newton's method will converge to the unique root of $f$ in $[a,b]$, for any initial approximation $x_0 \in[a,b]$. You can find the proof in elementary numerical analysis texts. Your situation falls in this framework.

Thank you which theorem is this?

One more theorem (which I mean in comment):
Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable and $x_0$ a simple root of $f$. That is $f(x_0)=0$  and $f'(x_0)\ne 0$. Then there is a closed interval $[a,b]$ such, that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ given by formula
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
converges to $x_0$ for any initial guess from $[a,b]$. Moreover, the convergence is quadratic with
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^2}=\frac{f''(x_0)}{2f'(x_0)}$$
where $e_n=x_n-x_0$.
Addition 1:
Using stated in comment let's consider $g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, for $f(x)=x^4-9$, with simple root $\sqrt 3$. $g(x)=\frac 3 4 x + \frac {9}{4x^3}$, $g(\sqrt 3)=\sqrt 3$.
Having $g'(x)=\frac 3 4  - \frac{27}{4x^4}$, with $g'(\sqrt 3)=0$, we can solve inequality
$$|g'(x)|=\left | \frac 3 4  - \frac{27}{4x^4}\right | < 1$$
which gives $|x|>\sqrt [4]{\frac{27}{7}}$.
Because, $\sqrt [4]{6} > \sqrt [4]{\frac{27}{7}}$ we obtain, that Newton iteration is convergent for any point from $(\sqrt[4]{6},100)$.
Addition 2
Brought theorem can be found in Dimitrios Mitsotakis - Computational Mathematics_ An introduction to Numerical Analysis and Scientific Computing with Python (Advances in Applied Mathematics)-Chapman and Hall, 2023, page 146. Condition $\max|g'|\leqslant K < 1$ and appropriate theorem on page 140.

The conditions you mention do not guarantee convergence for all $x_0 \in [a,b]$.

Which $[a,b]$ you have in view @PierreCarre? In my answer I have $\exists$.

My bad... I did not realize you were giving a local convergence result.

@zkutch This doesn't answer the question, which is to prove that the sequence converges for any $x_{0}\in (\sqrt[4]{6},100)$.

Again, @mathcounterexamples.net, do you see $\exists [a,b]$ in my answer?

As I see it, you still need to argue for monotone convergence. If the Newton sequence were oscillating around the root, then the proven properties would not guarantee that if $x_0$ is close to $b=100$ that the next iterate $x_1$ is still in the interval, especially not below $a=\sqrt[4]6$

$\exists [a,b]  , (\sqrt[4]{6},100) \subset [a,b] \subset \left(\sqrt [4]{\frac{27}{7}}, \infty \right )$ such, that $\max\limits_{[a,b]} |g'|\leqslant K < 1$.

Having brought condition we do not need to worry about monotony, @Lutz Lehmann.

You still need to provide the first condition in all fixed-point theorems, that you have a complete metric space $(X,d)$ and a continuous function that maps the space into itself.

Well, you refuse your monotony requirement and now start think about existence of fixed point. But we have everything for given particular function. You can take look at book mentioned and yourself check if all conditions holds.

Let $g$ be a twice differentiable map on the interval $ I = [a, b]$, such that $g^\prime, g^{\prime \prime} > 0$ on $I$ and $g(a) = 0$. Now suppose that $c \in (a,b)$ and let $D_c$ be the tangent to the graph of $g$ at $c$.
Because $g$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, $g(c) > 0$. Also, $D_c$ is below the graph of $g$ as the graph of $g$ is convex ($g^{\prime \prime} >0$).
Denote by $d$ the abscissa of the intersection of $D_c$ with the horizontal axis, which exists as $g^\prime(c) >0$. We have:

$d < c$ as $D_c$ has a positive slope and $g(c) > 0$.
$a < c$ because $D_c$ is below the graph of $g$.

Coming back to Newton's method, this means that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ for $g$ is strictly decreasing and satisfies $x_n > a$.  Therefore $\{x_n\}$ converges to a value $l$ such that
$$l = l - \frac{g(l)}{g^\prime(l)}.$$
We finally get $g(l) = 0$, which means that $l=a$.
Apply that by taking $g = f$, $a = \sqrt[4]{6}$ and $b = 100$, you get the desired result.
Note: making a drawing greatly help to understand what happens!

This is confusing. Usually $f$ is the function to find a root for, and $g$ is the iteration function that hopefully has a root of $f$ as a fixed point. How is $f(a)=0$? Did you mean $f(a)\le 0$? If the given $a$ is the root, why iterate? And if $a$ is not a root, how to ensure that the whole interval is still admissible start points for the iteration?

$g$ is here whatever map satisfying the hypothesis in the introduction of my answer. I then apply the proven results to the map $f$ of the question.

Ok, that works too. Still, with the data of the question $f(a)=0$ does not hold. Your proof only applies to the interval $[l,b]$.

@LutzLehmann Thanks! I missed the fact that $a=\sqrt[4]{6}$ and not $a=\sqrt[4]{9}$. I should also state that whatever the value of $\sqrt[4]{9} \neq x_0 >0$, we have $x_1 > \sqrt[4]{9} = a$.
